# Tkinter calling functions within classes

Tags: function, class, python-3.x, tkinter

In my new program, I kept having the same lines of code show up, so I decided to make a function, and call it when I want. But I keep getting an error that tells me "my function in not defined". I am new to Python programming and I can't figure it out!

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        #Window_Creation
        scr_xloc = int(self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - 800 / 2)
        scr_yloc = int(self.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - 600 / 2 - 30)

        self.geometry("800x600+{}+{}".format(scr_xloc, scr_yloc))
        self.minsize(width = 800, height = 600)
        ...

    def Factorial_Calculation():
        user_input = int(float(user_input))
        import math

        factorial_num = math.factorial(user_input)

        self.Output_Box.delete("1.0", "end")
        self.Output_Box.insert("1.0", str(user_input) + "! = " + str(factorial_num))

    def x_Factorial_Loop(self, event):
        global user_input
        ...

        Factorial_Calculation()
```

Comment: Your indentation might be off. Do you have a mix of tabs and spaces?

Comment: What is the exact and complete error message that you are getting?

Comment: NameError: name 'Factorial_Calculation' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the calling of `Factorial_Calculation()`, you should call it within the class as `self.Factorial_Calculation()` but outside of the class is a different thing. Add "`self.`" in front of your called function, as it applies to that class you called it in and pulls up the definition from the class you called it in.

Comment: Is need it to put a "self" inside the parenthesis? def Factorial_Calculation(self):

Comment: Precisely, but only for the definition, otherwise when calling it, just do the usual `Factorial_Calculation()`,